# Non-standard circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, charge, electric-current

I partially solved this problem.

> **Problem**: A charged sphere of radius $a$ is connected through a resistance $R$ to the earth. An electronic flow breaks out towards the sphere of infinity at speed $v$ and with the number of particles in unit volume $n_{e}$. Determine the limit charge of the sphere. Consider the speed of the particles large (measure in comparison to what magnitude).

*My solution*: Let $Q$ be the charge of the sphere at some instant of time $t$, and $I$ be the current flowing through the resistor at this same instant of time. Using Ohm's law we will have

\begin{equation}
IR=\dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}a}\qquad (1).
\end{equation}

After a time $\Delta t\ll t$ the increase in charge on the sphere is $\Delta Q=\Delta Q_{e}+\Delta Q_{R}$. Here $\Delta Q_{e}=n_{e}e\pi a^{2}v\Delta t$ is the charge that comes from the electronic flow, and $\Delta Q_{R}=-IR$ is the charge that escapes through the resistance $R$. Then

\begin{equation}
\Delta Q=n_{e}e\pi a^{2}v\Delta t-I\Delta t\quad\Rightarrow\quad \dfrac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=n_{e}e\pi a^{2}v-I\qquad (2).
\end{equation}

Using the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=n_{e}e\pi a^{2}v-\dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}Ra}
\end{equation}

When the charge on the sphere is maximum we will have $\dfrac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad Q_{max}=4\pi^{2}\epsilon_{0}a^{3}en_{e}Rv$.

**My question is**: According to the solution to the problem, this solution is valid if $v\ll a^{2}e^{2}n_{e}R/m_{e}$, where $m_{e}$ is the electron mass, I am not able to reach this conclusion.If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.[image]